# Literature Regarding Exit Time Ito Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Im am looking for literature for the following problem:

Let $X_t$ be an Ito process defined by

$$
dX_t = b(t,X_t)dt+c(t,X_t)dB_t
$$

where $b,c:\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are Lipschitz-continuous functions in the second variable and $(B_t)$ is the standard Brownian motion. Let $\tau  = \inf \left \{ t > 0 \ | \ X_t \in (0,N)^c \right \}$ for some $N > 0$. I want to determine (if possible) $\mathbb{P}(X_{\tau} = N)$.

If you know some usefull literature, or any other tips are really appreciated!

Much thanks in advance

Comment: 1) There is no connexion between your SDE and $\tau$. 2) If $b,c$ are continuous, there is a priori no chance to have any solution to your SDE. 3) Exit time of the Brownian motion of a bounded domain is covered in the Book *Stochastic Differential Equation* of Oksendal (and require only Dynkin Formula). 4) For solution of SDE, exit time are covered in *Large Deviation Techniques and Application* by Dembo and Zeitouni.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There was a mistake in the definition of $\tau$. The $B_t$ should have been $X_t$, i have fixed it. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I changed the continuity of b,c to Lipschitz continuity in the second variable to assure the existence of a strong solution,